# Generate two random numbers between 1 to 10 using specific string

Tags: java, algorithm, random, numbers

I would like to implement a logic based on a provided string I have to generate two random numbers between  1 to 10.

I have a string like **Johnsen** using it I have to generate two numbers like 1 and 3 and next time with the same string it should give the same numbers for the same string.

Need help to develop this algorithm or logic.

Comment: If it produces the same values from the same string, it's not random.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has random number generator support via the `java.util.Random` class. This class 'works' by having a seed value, then giving you some random data based on this seed value, which then updates the seed value to something new.

This pragmatically means:

- 2 instances of j.u.Random with the same seed value will produce the same sequence of values if you invoke the same sequence of calls on it to give you random data.
- But, seed values are of type `long` - 64 bits worth of data.
- Thus, to do what you want, you need to write an algorithm that turns any String into a `long`.
- Given that long, you simply make an instance of `j.u.Random` with that long as seed, using the [`new Random(seedValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random-long-) constructor.

So that just leaves: How do I turn a string into a long?

### Easy way

The simplest answer is to invoke `hashCode()` on them. But, note, hashcodes only have 32 bits of info (they are `int`, not `long`), so this doesn't cover all possible seed values. This is unlikely to matter unless you're doing this for crypto purposes. If you ARE, then you need to stop what you are doing and do a lot more research, because it is extremely easy to mess up and have working code that seems to test fine, but which is easy to hack. You don't want that. For starters, you'd want `SecureRandom` instead, but that's just the tip of the iceberg.

### Harder way

Hashing algorithms exist that turn arbitrary data into fixed size hash representations. The hashCode algorithm of string [A] only makes 32-bits worth of hash, and [B] is not cryptographically secure: If you task me to make a string that hashes to a provided value I can trivially do so; a cryptographically secure hash has the property that I can't just cook you up a string that hashes to a desired value.

You can search the web for hashing strings or byte arrays (you can turn a string into one with `str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`).

You can 'collapse' a byte array containing a hash into a long also quite easily - just take any 8 bytes in that hash and use them to construct a long. "Turn 8 bytes into a long" also has tons of tutorials if you search the web for it.

I assume the easy way is good enough for this exercise, however.

### Thus:

```
String key = ...;
Random rnd = new Random(key.hashCode());

int number1 = rnd.nextInt(10) + 1;
int number2 = rnd.nextInt(10) + 1;

System.out.println("First number: " + number1);
System.out.println("Second number: " + number2);
```

Comment: If you want a specific size hash, and don't require cryptographic level security, then the [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) is simple to code and comes in a range of sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the hashcode of the string, then use that to seed a random number generator. Use the RNG to get numbers in the range 1 - 10.

Comment: Or just take the last 2 digits of the hashcode (and add 1 to each).

Comment: @Olivier Yes, that will work. Those should be just as "random" as the first two results from the RNG for this purpose.